# How to configure Keycloak 21.0.1 to use redis session store

Tags: redis, keycloak, spring-session, keycloak-services

I'm looking for some guidance on how to configure Keycloak version 21.0.1 to use Redis for session storage. I've searched around and found many answers on this topic, but they all seem to be for previous versions of Keycloak which have directories that don't exist in the latest version.

I tried to create a standalone file in the **conf** directory which contains:

```
<spi name="session-store">     
   <provider name="redis" enabled="true"> 
        <properties>             
             <property name="redisConnectionJson" value="providers/redis.json"/>             
              <property name="poolSize" value="20"/>             
              <property name="singlePool" value="true"/>        
        </properties>     
    </provider>
 </spi>
```

Then added the **redis.json** file in the providers directory:

```
{   
     "id": "redis",
      "provider": "redis", 
      "host": "localhost", 
      "port": 6379, 
      "database": 0, 
      "password": "xxxx",  
      "timeout": 5000, 
      "keyPrefix": "keycloak-session:" 
}
```

finally I rebuild the server before launching it.

As if keycloak server ignored changes and didn't support added files..

My goal is to share the same Redis session store between Keycloak and a Spring Boot API which uses Spring Session + Redis. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.